# Adding a string to highcharts tooltip based on a separate data series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a bar chart in highcharts using data from a django database back-end

the bar chart is plotting fine however, I need to show the ‘contact_note’ string in addition to the y-values upon hovering in the tooltip

The data from the database is being served in the following json format

```
{
  "chart_data": {
    "dates": [
      "12/12/16",
      "01/28/17",
      "02/10/17",
    ],
    "values": [
      9.0,
      47.0,
      13.0,
    ],
    "contact_notes": [
      "aa",
      "bb",
      "cc"
    ]
  }
}
```

the dates represent the x-axis, the 'values' are the y-axis and I would like the tooltip to include the contents of the 'contact_note' field

Here’s my highcharts code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

     var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart_panel',
            type: 'column',
        },
        legend: {enabled: false},
        title: {text: 'Days Between Meetings'},
        tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return "<span style='color:" + this.point.color + "'>\u25CF</span> " + this.series.name + " : <b>" + this.point.y + "</b> " +  contact_notes[this.point.index] + "<br/>";
        }},
        xAxis: {title: {text: null}, labels: {rotation: -45}},
        yAxis: {title: {text: null},
        plotLines: [{
                value: 20,
                color: 'orange',
                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                width: 1.5}]
        },
        plotOptions: {column: {dataLabels: {enabled: true}}},
        series: [{}],
    };


    var chartDataUrl = "{% url 'chart_data' pk %}"

    $.getJSON(chartDataUrl,
        function(data) {
            options.xAxis.categories = data['chart_data']['dates'];
            options.series[0].name = 'Days between contacts';
            options.series[0].data = data['chart_data']['values'];

            var contact_notes = data['chart_data']['contact_notes'];

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

} );

</script>
```

Is there a simple way for me to append the contact notes to the series tooltip?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, save the data from the backend somewhere (I just left it in your returned data object) and use the `tooltip` `formatter` function.  The `point` is passed into the `formatter` and it has an `index` that you can use to index into your array.

http://jsfiddle.net/yjL551vp/

```
  tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return "<span style='color:" + this.point.color + "'>\u25CF</span> " + this.series.name + " : <b>" + this.point.y + "</b> " +  data.chart_data.contact_notes[this.point.index] + "<br/>";
        }
    },
```

EDIT:
Your current problem is that contact_notes is defined within your getJSON function, so it's out of scope in the formatter function.  Define the var outside the getJSON function

```
   var chartDataUrl = "{% url 'chart_data' pk %}"
   var contact_notes = [];
    $.getJSON(chartDataUrl,
        function(data) {
            options.xAxis.categories = data['chart_data']['dates'];
            options.series[0].name = 'Days between contacts';
            options.series[0].data = data['chart_data']['values'];

            contact_notes = data['chart_data']['contact_notes'];

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - when i do that, I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined". Is it because I'm referencing the data.chart_data.contact_note object before I've saved the chartDataUrl variable?  I've updated my code to show what I am now doing

Comment: hi barbara - any chance you could help me figure out why i'm getting a reference error? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you so much!!